# Каким образом можно представить алгоритм в наглядном виде?

Tags: алгоритм, uml, моделирование

К примеру UML или что-то ещё... Бывает программа уже слишком длинная для того, чтобы прокрутить её в уме, хотя начиналось все с более менее четкого плана, опять же в уме.

Потом в некоторых местах пошли костыли или же промежуток в несколько дней между написанием и цепочка понимания пропала.

Есть ощущения что нужно оптимизировать, но опять же сложно восстановить цепочку, а осматривать отдельные участки недостаточно, так как много взаимосвязей.

UML Диаграммы пробовал раньше на примитивных примерах, так что не знаю насколько они помогают. Также не читал книги по оптимизации или рефакторингу , наверное в этом и есть проблема.

Каким образом можно достичь понимания работы всей программы в наглядном виде?

Comment: Блокнот и карандаш.

Comment: любимый редактор - перед тем как написать код, пишу код комментариями, теперь часто сразу и тесты.

Конечно, обычный бумажный блокнот или доску никто не отменял.

Comment: Если сложно восстановить логику — вероятно, вы что-то делаете не так. Разбейте методы (и классы!) на мелкие, выполняющие одну задачу, старайтесь избавится от неявных побочных эффектов. Глядя на название метода, вы должны понимать, что он делает. Ваш код должен быть кристально чист и самоочевиден, причём так, что даже комментарии не нужны.

Comment: @VladD, если комментарии описывают, что делает код, то можно согласиться.

А вот комментарии *для чего этот код (переменная) вообще нужен* -- без них никуда.

Да и не стоит так уж полагаться на "правильные" имена (а уж от длинных то имен, просто будет рябить в глазах и даже логически кристально чистый код станет невоспринимаемым (пока прочтешь -- забудешь о чем речь)).

Comment: @avp: Из моей практики, если переменная требует слишком длинного имени для описания — _что-то не так с алгоритмом_. Область ответственности переменной должна описываться простой фразой, иначе надо разбивать алгоритм на части.

Но я люблю короткие функции, [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сверху вниз. На самом верхнем уровне мы пишем тех. документацию / спецификации. В документации описываем общее устройство системы (фронтенд, масштабируемый бэкенд, открытый API) и спускаемся до протоколов коммуникаций между узлами. Должно быть понятно новому разработчику без дополнительных пояснений.

Реализация описанного в каждом из независимых друг от друга узлов - понятна и прозрачна за счет вроде бы грамотной модульности: общепринятые паттерны, пространства имён, классы, методы. Стараемся держать хозяйство в порядке, все разложено по полочкам. По возможности комментируем код. Как минимум, классы, крупные и наследуемые методы.

Стартап, быстро развиваемся, «нет времени объяснять», далеко не всё идеально или даже просто надёжно, но на плаву держимся, новых людей подключаем к разработке. Наверное, это и есть критерий понятности — если удается без проблем вводить новых людей в разработку проекта. Тогда и самому удастся разобраться в коде после поездки в Амстердам : )

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Вот несколько инструментов для создания блок-схем:

1. Общеизвестная штука, как листок бумаги и карандаш.
2. [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visio/)
3. [Вот такое чудо](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part)